# How to debug an outlook plugin project from desktop outlook

Tags: javascript, c#, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-2019

I have developed an Outlook plugin using the Outlook plugin project in Visual Studio. The plugin works as expected in web Outlook, but when opened in desktop Outlook, the login screen appears initially, but when I try to log in, it just stays on the same page. There is no error in the server-side code. To investigate the issue, I need to debug from desktop Outlook and identify what's wrong.

If anyone has experience with this issue, please let me know the solution.

I am expecting to be able to debug the client side code from the plugin in desktop outlook.

Comment: Do you develop an Outlook web add-in or COM add-in? How are C# and JavaScript related to each other?

Comment: I am developing an Outlook web add-in, I am using outlook plugin project for the client side and Web Api for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to debug,

Steps:

- Open outlook, and right click on your plugin. you will get the
  following menu box.

[image]

- click on the Attach debugger option here. You will get the following
  Choose just-In-Time Debugger box.

[image]

- Here, select your project and click ok.  Now when you run the
  project.the debug point is getting hit.

**Note:** Your project should not be running,that is when your project will be listed here.